# Is there any API in JUnit 5 to test for included or excluded Tags?

Tags: junit5

I'd like to enable a test if a certain tag is "included", i.e. passed with option `--include-tag` of the ConsoleLauncher or `useJUnitPlatform.includeTags` property in Gradle. Is there any API to retrieve the value of this option in the context of test class or method?

I tried the script-based condition @EnabledIf like this:

```
@EnabledIf("'true' == systemProperty.get('itest.backendSystemPresent') || junitTags.contains('BackendSystemIT') == true")
```

But `junitTags` contains the @Tag annotations of the element in question, not the tags included at runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading your question again, my answer is **"No"**. You can't use `junitTags` to achieve your goals. And no, there's no such API at the moment. You would need something like:

```
@EnabledIf("'true' == evaluateTagExpression('BackendSystemIT') || ...)
```

Because you need to take care of tag expression here as well: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-tag-expressions

**But**, tags are evaluated earlier in the process. Your condition will not get a chance to be executed when the test was already excluded by tag evaluation. So, I guess, you'll have to stick with the single system property switch to control the enabled state of the test method.

Btw. we are improving the tag expression language with `any()` and `none()` tokens, soon. https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1679

Possible **solution**:

1. Annotate your test with `@Tag("BackendSystemIT")`
2. Before running your tests, check for `itest.backendSystemPresent` system property and if it is set, pass a `--include-tag "BackendSystemIT"` to the test run.
3. Let Jupiter do the job of evaluating tag expressions

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any API to retrieve the value (*of this option*) **of all tags that are attached directly or inherited** in the context of test class or method?

Yes. Declare and use a `org.junit.jupiter.api.TestInfo` parameter in your test method.

```
@Test
@DisplayName("TEST 1")
@Tag("my-tag")
void test1(TestInfo testInfo) {
    assertEquals("TEST 1", testInfo.getDisplayName());
    assertTrue(testInfo.getTags().contains("my-tag"));
}
```

For details see https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-dependency-injection

> But junitTags contains the @Tag annotations of the element in question, not the tags included at runtime.

This is the expected behaviour -- the platform (here: console launcher) already applied the filter passed via `--include-tag` and other configuration parameters. In short: there's no need to manually check for tags in standard Jupiter tests. If there's problem with the built-in filtering, please create an issue here: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/new/choose